# Does the ubuntu image in GCP Compute not use systemctl?

Tags: nginx, debian, systemctl

I've downloaded nginx into my debian 10 server. GCP Compute instance. When I run the command in cloud terminal to start it:

```
> sudo systemctl start nginx
```

I get this error:

```
> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Really any operation with `systemctl` doesn't work.

How would I get nginx running? does Debian not have `systemctl`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

can try nginx directly

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```